# Unset environment variable in compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile that requires two environment variables:

```
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

I'm passing them from the host through my compose file using:

```
build:
  # ...
  args:
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

My problem is that in some flows there is an IAM role set (and no env vars) and I don't want to use the environment variables. But even when they don't exist on the host they seem to be set to empty strings during the build process.

I've tried this:

```
run if [ -z "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" ]; then unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID; fi
run if [ -z "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" ]; then unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY; fi

run env # see if set
```

But it doesn't work (the variables are still set even if not set in host env).

I'd welcome another solution on mixing env vars and IAM roles when building dockers.

Comment: Currently I'm constantly chaining the unset with the layer that requires it. But it is reptitive and probably messes up the caching mechanism... :(

Answer (score 1):

Different `run` in `Dockerfile` not impact each other, to make your aims, suggest to combine them to one `run`, something likes follows, FYI:

```
run if [ -z "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" ]; then unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID; fi && \
  if [ -z "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" ]; then unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY; fi && \
  env
```

Then, you will find no `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` was set to empty value in `env`.

And, when try, suggest use `docker-compose build --no-cache` to test.

Finally, why you see empty value?

I made a experiment, seems if no `ENV` set in `Dockerfile`, meanwhile, no `env for this variable set` in HOST, the `ARG` in `Dockerfile` will automatically be changed to `one ENV variable` when docker build, as the `ARG` did not set a value, so it's empty.